# How to skip local dependencies using Maven

Tags: maven

I have a local jar project like so:

```
    <groupId>com.oresoftware</groupId>
    <artifactId>async.0.1</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>0.1.101</version>
    <name>org.ores.async.Asyncc</name>
    <url>https://github.com/ORESoftware/async.java</url>
```

in another Maven project, I refer to it with:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.oresoftware</groupId>
  <artifactId>async.0.1</artifactId>
  <version>0.1.101</version>
</dependency>
```

if I run `mvn clean install` from my library, I believe the other project will use the local dependency. My question is - how can I test the dependency that comes from the network?

```
mvn clean install -DskipLocalDeps
```

Is there some maven command that can ignore locally created dependencies? And only install dependencies retrieved from the network?

**update:**

I think one solution would just be to delete the folder in .m2 and then reinstall in the test project:

```
rm -rf ~/.m2/com/oresoftware
mvn clean install
```

then it will have to go to the network to try to find the dep. I am sure this will work, but not sure if it's the optimal workflow

Comment: Can you explain what the purpose is of this request? What do you mean by "network" ? Usually you develop a lib which has a SNAPSHOT version....which can be used for tests (ok better having good unit/integration tests in your library)...and after making a release it's released..if you might find an issue you have to create a new version (release) of it?

Comment: i am developing the dep locally, after publishing, i want to test whats online, not whats local

Comment: What kind of tests is needed after done a release? Either the artifact works or not..which can already being tested during the development via unit/integration tests ? What kind of issue are you trying to test/solve? What is the use case here?

Answer (score 1):

No, that's how the whole dependency resolution works (via the local repository). First it will check in local repository and if not present in the local repository then in central repository.

Comment: sure but if you are developing a library locally, and publish it, how can you test the published version?

Comment: I updated the OP, I think one solution is given there, but not sure if it's the best one